# How to call an element if its child contains some custom-filtered text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, regex

Suppose we have a page that contains the following:

```
<div data-search="type1">
any html
<!-- that is, .click is a child of any level -->
<span class="click" data-source="page1.html">blue</span>
<!-- let's call it "click1" -->
<span class="click" data-source="page1.html">  blue <span class="variable">thing</span>  </span>
<!-- let's call it "click2" -->
<span class="click" data-source="page1.html"> blue<span class="variable">bell</span></span>
<!-- let's call it "click3" -->
any html
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

page1.html:

```
<div class="container">
any html
<span data-search="type1">blue</span>
any html
</div>
<div class="container">
any html
<span data-search="type1">blue <span class="variable">flower</span></span>
any html
</div>
<div class="container">
any html
<span data-search="type1">  blue    <span class="variable">shirt</span></span>
any html
</div>
<div class="container">
any html
<span data-search="type1">non-matching html</span>
<!-- no match inside, skip this .container -->
any html
</div>
<div class="container">
any html
<span data-search="type2">blue</span>
<!-- "data-search" attribute doesn't match a "data-search" attribute of the first "data-search"-attribute-containing element that we encounter when we traverse from .click up the DOM, so skip this .container -->
any html
</div>
<div class="container">
any html
<span data-search="type1">blue<span class="variable">berry</span></span>
<!-- no space after "blue", so "berry" is a part of the word -->
any html
</div>
```

After clicking the ".click" element, I want to use `$.get` method.
For "click1" element, I want #content to be

```
<div id="content">
<div class="container">
any html
<span data-search="type1">blue</span>
any html
</div>
</div>
```

For "click2" element, I want #content to be

```
<div id="content">
<div class="container">
any html
<span data-search="type1">blue <span class="variable">flower</span></span>
any html
</div>
<div class="container">
any html
<span data-search="type1">  blue    <span class="variable">shirt</span></span>
any html
</div>
</div>
```

For "click3" element, I want #content to be

```
<div id="content">
<div class="container">
any html
<span data-search="type1">blue<span class="variable">berry</span></span>
<!-- no space after "blue", so "berry" is a part of the word -->
any html
</div>
</div>
```

I don't know if it's tricky, but I have no such scripting skills and it's just very interesting to me, so please help me or tell me why the idea is bad.

**EDIT: THE PREVIOUS VERSION OF MY QUESTION WAS INCORRECT, SO I REVISED IT.**
If I'm supposed to show what have I tried I can show where I am now. This script doesn't work. 
(I'm simplifying the regex and just deleting the whole `.variable` element)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.click').click(function () {
            $("#content").empty();
            var search = $(this).html().replace(/<span class=\"variable\">(.*?)<\/span>/i, "");
            var type = $(this).parents('[data-search]').first().attr('data-search');
            var page = $(this).attr('data-source');
            $.get(page, {}, function (data) {
                var $response = $('<div />').html(data);
                var $content = $response.find('.container').filter(function (index) {
                    return $(this).contents().filter(function (index) {
                        return $(this).attr('data-search') == type && $(this).html().replace(/<span class=\"variable\">(.*?)<\/span>/i, "") == search;
                    }).length > 0;
                });
                $('#content').append($content);
            }, 'html');
        });
    });
</script>
```

But even if click `<span class="click" data-source="page1.html">blue</span>` and expect `<div class="container">any html<span data-search="type1">blue</span>any html</div>` to appear, nothing happens.
The problem is that I have no idea how to return all the containers with at least one element that matches this filter: `$(this).attr('data-search') == type && $(this).html().replace(/<span class=\"variable\">(.*?)<\/span>/i, "") == search`.

And I should clarify the logic for a regular expression.
1. The whole `.variable` element is replaced with one special symbol (say, asterisk);
2. whitespaces, tabs and linebreaks between the non-space characters are replaced with one space char;
3. whitespaces, tabs and linebreaks in the beginning and in the end of the `.click`/`[data-search]` element are removed.

For example, `.click`/`[data-search]` element of this structure:

```
<span>   match<span class="variable">variable1</span>    <span class="variable">variable2</span> match</span>
```

becomes

```
<span>match* * match</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a set of regular expressions that will match your three points :

```
// Remove .variable element
input = input.replace(/<span\s+class\s*=\s*"variable">.+?<\/span>/img, '*');

// Replace whitespaces, tabs and linebreaks between the non-space characters with one space char
input = input.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');

// Remove whitespaces, tabs and linebreaks in the beginning and in the end
input = input.replace(/^\s*<span>\s*/m, "<span>");
input = input.replace(/\s*<\/span>\s*$/m, "</span>");
```

**DEMO**
http://jsfiddle.net/NuBre/

Comment: Thanks, but now I know the regexp is not a problem at all, the problem is to collect all the containers which contain matching elements...